# Difference between two Android Firebase references

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

What is the difference between

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users")
            .child("Accounts")
            .child("AC123");
```

and

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users")
            .child("Accounts")
            .orderByKey()
            .equalTo("AC123");
```

using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` seems to return the same DataSnapshot in that the `toString()` values are the same and using DataSnapshot.getValue() seems to return identical HashMaps but only the first reference reports that it "has children".

Trying to query for children in the second reference just throws a NPE.

```
{
  "Users" : {
  "Accounts" : {
    "AC123" : {
      "linked" : true,
      "sort" : 0,
      "type" : 1
    }
  },   
etc
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON (as text, no screenshot) that you're accessing. Also: if you have code that throws an NPE, share the [minimal code that reproduces that exception](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The above snippets won't.

Comment: I don't need help with the NPE as I already know it is caused by the DataSnapshot having no children but I have added a Json sample.  This is a very general question. I just didn't understand why the snapshots returned by these references behave differently when they return the same node and seem to be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries don't return the same node.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

This means that the second query returns a subset of the nodes under `/Users/Accounts`. To access the individual matched nodes, you will need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()`, even when there's only a single matching child.

The first query always returns a single node, the one at `/Users/Accounts/AC123`. So the child's data is immediately available under `snapshot.getValue()`.

Comment: I see. so for the first reference, `dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue()` correctly returns 1 but for the second reference, I would have to de-serialize and check the hashmap in order to find the value?  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Nope, you have to loop over the `snapshot.getChildren()`. Also see the sample in the [documentation on filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data).